# Фрагмент, реализующий View.OnClickListener, не видит onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-on-click, onclicklistener

Есть код:

```
 class ShoppingCart : Fragment(),View.OnClickListener {
    
        private var binding: FragmentShoppingCartBinding? = null
        private var cardAdapter: ShoppingCartAdapter? = null
        private val cardViewModel: CardViewModel by viewModel()
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
    
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_shopping_cart, container, false)
            initRecyclerCard()
            loadClothesFromCard()
    
            return binding?.root
    
        }
    
        // обработка кликов по кнопкам
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
          //  loadClothesFromCard()
            when(view.id) {
                // очистка корзины
                R.id.clearCard -> cardViewModel.clearCard()
    
    
            }
        }
..................................................
    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку `clearCard` ничего не происходит

Провёл дебаг - код внутри `onClick(view: View)` даже не запускается

Comment: на кнопку повесьте setOnClockListener

Comment: А с чего бы `onClick(...)` в фрагменте должен вызываться?